# How to connect two classes to read information from the database?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm new to PHP PDO OOP. I'm trying to create a database connection using `__constructor`.
It's my database class code.

```
<?php
// database class
class Database
{
    // database host name
    private $db_host = "localhost";
    // database username
    private $db_user = "root";
    // database name
    private $db_name = "project_crud";
    // database password
    private $db_pass = "";

    public $conn;

    // function for create connection
    public function __construct()
    {
        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->db_host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
            $this->conn->exec("set names utf8");
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die("ERROR: Could not connect with database." . $e->getMessage());
        }
        return $this->conn;
    }
}
```

And it's my other class code.

```
<?php

class Employees
{
    private $conn;

    private $db_table = "employees";

    public function getConnection()
    {
        $this->conn = $ob ;
    }

    public function readAllEmployee()
    {
        $data   = array();
        $query  = "SELECT * FROM $this->db_table";
        $stmt   = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

It's my index code

```
<?php

include_once('database.php');
$db = new Database();

require_once("employee.php");
$obj = new Employees();
$obj->getConnection();

if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "view") {
    $output = '';
    $data = $obj->readAllEmployee();
    print_r($data);
}
```

Now I'm stuck to connect to classes to read information from the database.

Comment: Don't try-catch connection errors. You should not be catching any errors unless you intend on recovering from them.

Comment: What is the purpose of `foreach ($result as $row)`?

Comment: What's the purpose of `Employees` class? This looks like a single SQL statement

Comment: What's the point of saving `$db_host` and others as properties of the object? You are only ever going to use them once, are you not?

Comment: You should create another class, a trait if you like, which ahs the 'database connection logic' this can be 'used' in the two classes you have

Comment: Don't do `exec("set names utf8")`. You should set the correct charset (which is utf8mb4 btw) in the DSN inside of the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason to use OOP here. What you have is procedural code. You open a connection to PDO and you fetch some data from the database. There are no objects involved here.

In fact your whole code can be summarized in these few lines (after fixes):

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project_crud;charset=utf8mb4", 'root', 'password', [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, //on by default since PHP 8.0
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
]);

if('view' === filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action')) {
    print_r($pdo->query('SELECT * FROM employees')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
}
```

Object-oriented programming means that you should represent entities as classes. For example, `Employee` can be a class which will then have certain methods that will perform actions on the object. Such class can be composed of a PDO link if required, although you really have to consider whether your class does a single thing or multiple things (e.g. fetching from a database and performing actions on an employee object).

If you decide to implement such class then you can pass PDO connection in the following way:

```
class Employee
{
    private PDO $pdo;
    public function __construct(PDO $pdo)
    {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    public function getByID(int $id): ?array
    {
        $stmt =  $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE Id=?');
        $stmt->execute([$id]);
        return $stmt->fetch();
    }
}
```

Then when you create an instance of this class you pass PDO instance as an argument.

```
$emplpyee = new Employee($pdo);
$johndoe = $emplpyee->getByID(42);
```

**Careful now!** This is still not a proper OOP. As you can see our class does not act as an employee. In fact, it acts as a PDO wrapper for getting employees. This is something that PDO already offers, so that class can be reworked in the following way:

```
/**
 * Class representing a real life employee in a company
 */
class Employee {
    private $Id;

    private $Name;

    public function getName(): ?string {
        return $this->Name;
    }
}

// Execute prepared statement to to create a single employee object. 
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT Id, Name FROM employees ORDER BY Id LIMIT 1');
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, Employee::class);
$empl = $stmt->fetch();

echo $empl->getName();

// or if you want to fetch by an ID
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT Id, Name FROM employees WHERE Id=?');
$stmt->execute([1]); // pass ID of the employee
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, Employee::class);
$empl = $stmt->fetch();

echo $empl->getName();

// or if you need to fetch multiple employees
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT Id, Name FROM employees WHERE Id IN(?,?)');
$stmt->execute([1, 2]); // pass ID of the employee
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, Employee::class);
$employees = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($employees as $empl) {
    var_dump($empl->getName());
}
```

Now we have a class that has some methods and represents a single entity. The class is instantiated by PDO which creates an object and populates its properties. No need for passing PDO around or dealing with dependencies in your classes. Each class has a single responsibility.

Comment: The class is going to be extended with new methods. A toy Active Record. An inevitable step in the developer's development.